# Testing models with Translate behaviour

Tags: cakephp

I have the following test case in my CakePHP (2.0.1) app:

```
<?php
public function testGetTenUsers() {
    $users = $this->User->find('all' , array('limit' => 10));
    // .... assert some things
}
?>
```

This works fine, and returns 10 records from my fixture.

When I add the Translate behaviour to my User model, this test no longer works (returns empty array).

Not sure how to approach this. Do I create an I18n fixture, or unbind the behaviour?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Since someone else will surely find this... In addition to Vincent's instructions below; when writing tests for a model that `$actsAs = ['Translatable']` you must set **THAT** model's `$Model->locale = 'eng'` (or whatever code is appropriate) wherever that model is used in your tests. This includes when you fetch "associated" records from the translated model through another one. You also have to include your `app.i18n` fixture in your test classes.

Answer (score 2):

Like you just stated, the best solution is to create a fixture.

Unbinding this behavior will make your tests less likely to catch errors. My point is: The further you are from your production configuration, the more complex it becomes to find bugs and quirks.

Here is my default fixture for i18n:

```
<?php
// I'm working in CakePHP 1.3 at the moment
class I18nFixture extends CakeTestFixture {
    public $name = 'I18n';
    public $table = 'i18n';
    public $import = array(
        'table'=>'i18n', 
        'records'=>true
    );
}
```

I imported the rows in my i18n table from the default configuration, because I only have static content in it (i.e. translation for types, roles). I wouldn't recommend doing this if you have many user input stored in it.

Please also note that you have to specify the table name in the fixture if you want to avoid the inflector to kick in. (so your table name stays "i18n" and not "i18ns")